# Multiplying vectors of different length in R

Tags: r

I have a function:

```
v0 <- function(n) {
   seq(1:n)
}
```

and I need to create a function `v1` which gives this result:

```
(1 2 3 -4 -5 -6 7 8 9 -10)            # if n <- 10   or
(1 2 3 -4 -5 -6 7 8 9 -10 -11 -12 13) # if n <- 13
```

But I keep getting a warning message when I do:

```
v1 <- function(n) {
    seq(1:n) * c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)
}
```

Any tips on what is the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`V0(10)` is an array of length 10, while `c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)` has length 6.

The warning that you are getting ("longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length") is because 6 does not divide 10.

When you do `v0(10) * c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)`, R repeats the second array as many times in order to create an array of the same length as `v0(10)`. 
How? Like this:

```
v0(10) * c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1)
```

If this is not the result you wish to obtain, then either correct `v0(10)`, the second array, or create a function where you define the correct operation between these two arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see what you mean! I am sorry if i was unclear in my question but it is exactly the function part that I am unable to do. Would really appreciate it if you could offer your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
v1 <- function(n){
  t <- seq(1:n)
  t[c(rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 3))] <- t[c(rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 3))] * (-1)
  return(t)
  }

v1(10)
# [1]   1   2   3  -4  -5  -6   7   8   9 -10
```

Also have a read [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865095/why-do-i-get-warning-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-l) for more info about the warning