# Misunderstanding of functions in R

Tags: r, function, sum

I have a vector

```
p <- seq(0,1,length=11)
```

That I want to use as the independent variable in the summation

[image]

If I craft a function that codes the summation by hand

```
f <- function(a){
a^0*(1-a)^5+a^1*(1-a)^4+...
}
```

and pass it `p`, then I get the correct output and no errors are thrown

```
results <- f(p)
```

I can plot it, `results` is the right length, everything's kosher. It just looks really ugly so I wanted to use `sum()` instead and tried

```
i <- 0:5    
g <- function(a,i){
    sum(a^i*(1-a)^(5-i))
}
```

but when I attempt `g(p,i)` it throws the error

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I believe the reason I'm getting this error is answered [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865095/why-do-i-get-warning-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-l) quite nicely, especially the part about recycling. `sum` cycles through the `i` vector as well as `p` at the same time, then starts over with `p[7]` and `i[1]` when it runs into the end of `i`. My question, however, is what is the CORRECT way to simplify `f` into `g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you want to compute isn't naturally vectorized with respect to `p`. `sapply` is a natural choice for mapping non-vectorized functions over a vector:

```
f <- function(x){
  i <- 0:5
  sum(x^i*(1-x)^(5-i))
}

p <- seq(0,1,length=11)

sums <- sapply(p,f)
> sums
 [1] 1.0000 0.6643 0.4368 0.2923 0.2128 0.1875 0.2128
 [8] 0.2923 0.4368 0.6643 1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: If I wanted to pass my function additional vectors, how would I go about that with `sapply`? For example, if I wanted to set the length of the `i` vector outside of the `function` and pass it as `function(x,i)`, what would be the proper way to do that? Trying `sapply(p,f(p,i))` would put me right back in the same boat.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this,

```
p <- seq(0,1,length=11)
i <- 0:5
g <- function(a,i){
  a^i*(1-a)^(5-i)
}

plot(p, rowSums(outer(X = p, Y = i, FUN = g)))
```

To answer your question, I don't think there is *one correct way* to do this; a more functional approach might be

```
Reduce(function(s, x) s + g(p, x), x = 0:5, init=0)
```

but it's likely to be less efficient, and arguably less readable.

Comment: You're absolutely right, there isn't one correct way. Perhaps I should have said 'a correct' since my solution was clearly broken.

Comment: note that if `p` is a large vector the proposed sapply solutions will be less efficient

Comment: How large? It presently only has ~100 elements and I don't intend to make it larger.

Comment: in that case it won't make any difference and you can go with whichever solution feels most natural to you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
g <- function(a, i){
  sum(sapply(i, function(x)a ^ x * (1 - a) ^ (5 - x)))
}


p <- seq(0, 1, length = 11)
i <- 0:5
g(p, i)
# [1] 5.3999
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! I think perhaps I wasn't clear which vector I need to map but `sapply` is definitely what I needed.