# Removd rows which do not meet all values in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to clean a dataset in which some participants have answered all questionnaires, and some haven't. I am trying to filter this dataset based on whether a column "quest_id" (the questionnaire id) matches a vector of a pattern of questionnaire IDs for the experiment, per participant.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
questionnaire_ids <- c(15,16,18,14,10,7,11,12,13)
n_times <- c(1,1,8,7,13, 9, 15, 6, 8)
quest_responses <- rep(questionnaire_ids, n_times)

questionnaire_data <- test_data %>%
  select(user_id, user_status, quest_id, q_name, dv) %>%
  filter(user_status == "registered") %>%
  unique() %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  filter(quest_id %in% quest_responses)
```

However, I keep receiving the error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

Any suggestions are most welcome (particularly using dplyr/tidyverse).

Comment: What is `test_data`?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865095/why-do-i-get-warning-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-l

Comment: test_data is originally a data frame of 3876 observations of 12 variables which I then bring down to 5 variables of interest as can be seen in the use of the select() function above. 

I am trying to remove any users that do not have the pattern of questionnaire completion shown in quest_responses.

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected output. As far as I can guess, there is nothing wrong with dplyr steps. Apart from "group_by" step, seems pointless.