# R Shiny- Output error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, reactive

I have been working on a Shiny app that uses conditional filters to select tables within several categories and compare the columns contained inside the tables. My filter system seem to be working as expected until I added the input data and noticed the output was not changing after I changed the selections and received these warnings:

> Warning in df$var_1 == input$var_1 :   longer object length is not a
> multiple of shorter object length

> Warning in df$var_2 == input$var_2 :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865095/why-do-i-get-warning-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-l) I understand that "When you perform a boolean comparison between two vectors in R, the "expectation" is that both vectors are of the same length, so that R can compare each corresponding element in turn" but honestly it is still not clear to me how to change my code in Shiny to solve that problem.

Here you can see my code so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)



df<-test_2_filtros
ui<-(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Shiny App Conditional Filter Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var_1","Select a category",choices = unique(df$var_1), multiple = TRUE, selected= "red"),
      selectInput("var_2","Select a table",unique(df$var_2), multiple = TRUE, selected= "table1")
    ),
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
    
  )
)
)




server<-(function(session,input,output) {
  
  
  observe({
    print(input$var_1)
    x <- df$var_2[df$var_1 == input$var_1]
    updateSelectInput(session,"var_2","Select a table",choices = unique(x), selected= "table1" )
    
  })
  
  
  observe({
    productdata <- df$var_3[df$var_2 == input$var_2]
    
  })
  
  
  result <- reactive({
    
    
    tmp<-filter(df, var_2 %in% unique(x) & var_3 %in% unique(productdata))
    
    tmp%>% 
      dplyr::mutate(n = "Yes")%>%
      mutate(row_num = 1:n()) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = var_3, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No"))%>%
      select(-row_num)
                         
  })
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mytable<-DT::datatable(result(), filter= 'top',options = list(order=list(1,'asc'), dom='t', pageLength= 100, autoWidth = TRUE),rownames = FALSE)
    
    formatStyle(mytable, columns = NULL, fontWeight = styleEqual(c('No', 'Yes'), c('normal', 'bold')))
    
  
  
  
  
})
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here you can see my input:

**input**(df in the code above)

| var_1 | var_2 | var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| green | table3 | column3 |
| green | table3 | column3 |
| green | table3 | column3 |

An here is the output if all options were selected (in my code I set a different default selection)

**output**

| var_1 | var_2 | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this works

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


test_2_filtros <- structure(list(var_1 = c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                                           "blue", "green", "green", "green"), var_2 = c("table1", "table1", 
                                                                                         "table1", "table2", "table2", "table2", "table3", "table3", "table3"
                                           ), var_3 = c("column1", "column1", "column1", "column2", "column2", 
                                                        "column2", "column3", "column3", "column3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -9L))
df<-test_2_filtros
ui<-(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Shiny App Conditional Filter Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var_1","Select a category",choices = unique(df$var_1), multiple = TRUE, selected= "red"),
      selectInput("var_2","Select a table",unique(df$var_2), multiple = TRUE, selected= "table1"),
      selectInput("var_3","Select a product",unique(df$var_3), multiple = TRUE, selected= "column1")
    ),
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
    
  )
)
)




server<-(function(session,input,output) {
  
  
  observe({
    req(input$var_1)
    print(input$var_1)
    x <- df$var_2[df$var_1 %in% input$var_1]
    updateSelectInput(session,"var_2","Select a table",choices = unique(x), selected= "table1" )
    
  })
  
  
  observe({
    req(input$var_2)
    productdata <- df$var_3[df$var_2 %in% input$var_2]
    updateSelectInput(session,"var_3","Select a product",choices = unique(productdata), selected= "column1" )
  })
  
  
  result <- reactive({
    
  
    tmp<-dplyr::filter(df, var_2 %in% unique(input$var_2) & var_3 %in% unique(input$var_3))
    
    tmp%>% 
      dplyr::mutate(n = "Yes")%>%
      mutate(row_num = 1:n()) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = var_3, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No"))%>%
      select(-row_num)
    
  })
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mytable<-DT::datatable(result(), filter= 'top',options = list(order=list(1,'asc'), dom='t', pageLength= 100, autoWidth = TRUE),rownames = FALSE)
    
    formatStyle(mytable, columns = NULL, fontWeight = styleEqual(c('No', 'Yes'), c('normal', 'bold')))
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: perfect! it works! thank you!